# Having both ubuntu and openSUSE

Tags: 11.04

I currently have OpenSUSE 11.4 and I want to install Ubuntu 11.04.

Can I install ubuntu without erasing openSUSE so that I can use both of them?
If I can, please tell me how.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can.

- From within OpenSuse (`gparted` should be able to do this) or from a live CD you can create a **partition** that is big enough for Ubuntu (roughly at least 15+ Gb) and install using this empty partition.
- Ubuntu's installer will ask you what to do with OpenSuse and as long as you do not touch those partitions and use the new empty one you will be able to add Ubuntu to your setup.

Example with Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04:

[image]

Similar to this you will get OpenSuse in it.

- At the end of the installation you'll probably will be prompted what to do with grub (the bootloader). If you reinstall grub at this time it will add both OpenSuse and Ubuntu to it but you can also do this manually from within OpenSuse after install (also useful in case the installer does mess it up and only adds Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

fist，install the opensuse 11.4.
then, install the Ubuntu 11.o4, and do not install the grub on master partition.

then ,modify the Opensuse's grub config, add the entry of the ubuntu 11.04's boot option.